# Unable to Create Object in Foreach Loop in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, object, foreach

I am trying to create object using the foreach loop in PowerShell. Tried using "while" loop, it failed as well. Apparently, the looping methods are not allowing me to create objects...

Without further ado...

I have two scripts - Class.psm1 and Main.ps1.

On **Class.psm1**

```
Class Car {
    [string]$brand
    [string]$model
    [string]$color

    #Constructor
    Car ([string]$brand) {
         $this.brand = $brand

         switch -wildcard ($this.brand) {
             ('Toyota') {$this.model = 'ABC'; $this.color = 'red'; break}
             ('Honda') {$this.model = 'FGH'; $this.color = 'blue'; break}
         }
    }
}
```

And on **Main.ps1**

```
Using module ".\Class.psm1"

$AllCars = {'Toyota', 'Honda'}
[array]$Objects = @()

foreach ($car in $AllCars) {
    $temp = New-Object Car("$car")
    $Objects += $temp
}
```

The output from Main.ps1, is that $Objects are just returning back "Toyota" and "Honda", instead of objects (and the properties it supposed to have).

However, if I were to just create the object individually, it will works fine.

*For example:*

```
$temp = New-Object Car('Toyota')
$Objects += $temp
$temp = New-Object Car('Honda')
$Objects += $temp
```

However, this is too manual work or rather unpractical.

May I know in which area did the codes went wrong...? How do I create the objects within the loop?

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors in `Class.psm1` - all properties and parameters need `$` in front of the name

Comment: Hi Jessen, sorry, I typed in manually here (as the data was all made up) but in the codes are close to my exact codes with the correct syntax and so on. Thanks for spotting it, will change it here.

Comment: Did you perhaps edit your Class and tried without restarting PowerShell? Once loaded, changes to it are not recognized.

Comment: Hi Theo.. yes, you are right. Somehow, the Class file is the one needed a restart. It works afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is you are using `{'Toyota', 'Honda'}` instead of `('Toyota', 'Honda')`

`{'Toyota', 'Honda'}` is a code block. When you pass it to `New-Object Car("$car")` it is actually passing `New-Object Car("'Toyota', 'Honda'")`

```
$AllCars = ('Toyota', 'Honda')
[array]$Objects = @()

foreach ($car in $AllCars) {
    $temp = New-Object Car("$car")
    $Objects += $temp
}
```

Since i was asked why the kangaroo code I decided to post a shorter response

```
$Objects = 'Toyota', 'Honda' | %{
    New-Object Car("$car")
}
```

Comment: Why so  kangaroo code? Just use  `$AllCars = ('Toyota', 'Honda'); <#PleaseTypeANewLineHere#>;
$Objects = foreach ($car in $AllCars) { New-Object Car($car) }`

Comment: I was using his code above and just changed the one line. I didn't write anything different then what he had other then replace `{}` with `()`. So if you want to ask about kangaroo code ask the poster.

Comment: I'd leave out the brackets too, you just need `$AllCars = 'Toyota', 'Honda'` to declare the string array.

Comment: **I beg your pardon** for my _abusive_ wording. My poor vocabulary  translated it as _'too complex code'_ without any rude or opprobrious  connotation. Sorry.

Comment: @JosefZ No Problem Sorry for taking it the wrong way :)

Comment: Thanks ArcSet and JosefZ.Am quite new to scripting/programming language, and I thought the way i wrote was rather clear and organized... guess i still got a long way..  Will amend the codes on my side but I can only try it tomorrow, and will give an update afterwards!

Comment: Tried, and it works! As well as heeding @Theo's suggestion in restarting the "Class" file. Thanks..!